# Confused about relationship in EntityFrameworkCore

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

Currently im creating a web based game and i need help with the relationships in EF. Im using code first to make the tables, but i got confused. Here's the question:
How to make a `Player` has different types of `Weapons`? What is the type of the relationship between them?
In the Player model i have `ICollection<Weapon>`, but what do i do in the Weapons model? How to make the relationship, because the same weapon can be used by many users and every user can have multiple weapons?

Comment: The relationship between player and weapon should be many-to-many.

Comment: EF like all ORMs deals with **entities** not tables. Those entities get mapped to tables that may or may not look like the entities themselves

Comment: Sounds like you need a WeaponType to represent the type of weapon and a Weapon to represent the actual weapon. Unless players actually *share* weapons

Comment: Does each character use a copy of the same weapon, or is there only one of each weapon and only one character can use a certain weapon at a time?

Answer (score 0):

Store a Player in the weapon's model, this will show which user is currently using that weapon (or if the same weapon can be used by multiple players simultaneously then store a collection of Players in the weapon model).

Comment: You mean a `Player` instance. ORMs deal with entities, not tables. `PlayerId` is sometimes used to make mapping the entities to tables easier. The ORM's job though is to make working with *entities* easier

Answer (score 0):

You mean "Many-to-many" relationship, like this:

```
public class Phone
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
     
    public ICollection<Company> Companies { get; set; } // Many companies can develop this phone
 
    public Phone()
    {
        Companies = new List<Company>();
    }
}
 
public class Company
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
 
    public ICollection<Phone> Phones { get; set; } // The company can develop many phones
 
    public Company()
    {
        Phones = new List<Phone>();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use intermadia table.

```
public class Weapon
{
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public ICollection<PlayerWeapon> PlayerWeapons{ get; set; }
}
public class Player
{
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public ICollection<PlayerWeapon> PlayerWeapons{ get; set; }
}
public class PlayerWeapon
{
 public int Id { get; set; }
 public int PlayerId { get; set; }
 public int WeaponId{ get; set; }

 [ForeignKey("PlayerId")]
 public Player Player{ get; set; }

[ForeignKey("WeaponId")]
public Weapon Weapon { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In EF Core, for how to configure a many-to-many relationship, you should include an entity (PlayerWeapon) to represent the join table, and then add navigation properties to either side of the many-to-many relations that point to the join entity.

```
public class Player
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string PlayerName { get; set; }
    public ICollection<PlayerWeapon> PlayerWeapons { get; set; }
}

public class PlayerWeapon
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int PlayerId { get; set; }
    public Player Player { get; set; }
    public int WeaponId { get; set; }
    public Weapon Weapon { get; set; }
}

public class Weapon
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string WeaponName { get; set; }
    public ICollection<PlayerWeapon> PlayerWeapons { get; set; }
}
```

For more details, you can refer to this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships?tabs=fluent-api%2Cfluent-api-simple-key%2Csimple-key#many-to-many).

Answer (score 0):

I would assume that "Many players have many weapons" holds true in this context, therefore as already specified, you will need to model a many-to-many relationship, which requires the addition of a third *entity*.

```cs
public sealed class Player
{
    private readonly ICollection<PlayerWeapon> playerWeapons = new HashSet<PlayerWeapon>();

    public Player(String name, ...)
    {
        Name = name;
        ...
    }

    private Player()
    {
    }

    public Guid Id { get; private set; }
    public String Name { get; private set; }
    public IEnumerable<Weapon> => playerWeapons.Select(pw => pw.Weapon);
}

public sealed class Weapon
{
    private readonly ICollection<PlayerWeapon> playerWeapons = new HashSet<PlayerWeapon>();

    public Weapon(String name, ...)
    {
        Name = name;
        ...
    }

    private Weapon()
    {
    }

    public Guid Id { get; private set; }
    public String Name { get; private set; }
    public IEnumerable<Player> Players => playerWeapons.Select(pw => pw.Player);
}

public sealed class PlayerWeapon
{
    public PlayerWeapon(Player player, Weapon weapon)
    {
        Player = player;
        Weapon = weapon;
        PlayerId = Player.Id;
        WeaponId = Weapon.Id;
    }

    private PlayerWeapon()
    {
    }

    public Player Player { get; private set; }
    public Weapon Weapon { get; private set; }
    public Guid PlayerId { get; private set; }
    public Guid WeaponId { get; private set; }
}
```

Let's run through why I've written code this way...

All classes are `sealed`. I tend to seal classes in C# by default (unless there's a reason for them to be open, seal them). Note that you will need to remove `sealed` if you want to use lazy-loading in EF since EF will create proxy entities to perform lazy loading (that's why you also mark navigation properties as `virtual`, so that EF can proxy them with a lazy-loading implementation). Personally I prefer to use explicit or eager loading, hence my code is sealed and non-virtual, but that's up to you.

All classes have two constructors; a public constructor for consumers of the code to construct players, weapons and player/weapon pairs. They also have a private default constructor. This is needed for EF to construct your object and map to it. Again, if you want to use lazy-loading, these need to change from private to protected.

All properties of the classes are either read-only or have private setters. This is to favour immutability. EF can still write to properties with private setters, but will ignore read-only (or computed) properties altogether - they won't be persisted.

The `Player` and `Weapon` classes contain private readonly collections of `PlayerWeapon` which represents a mapping table, allowing your many-to-many relationship, but the weapons and players are expressed through computed, read-only `IEnumerable` properties which select the relevant item from the collection element. Note that for this to return actual values and not a collection of `null` elements you will need to tell EF to load these explicitly/eagerly (or change to using lazy-loading).

The `PlayerWeapon` class exposes `PlayerId` and `WeaponId`. This is because you need to use these to create a unique, composite key from them to ensure that you don't end up with duplicates. You will need to set that up in your fluent configuration/constraints when you specify how the entities map to the database.

For more information about why I model EF code like this, check out "Domain Modelling with Entity Framework scorecard" by Jimmy Bogard: https://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2014/04/29/domain-modeling-with-entity-framework-scorecard/